# QML module contains C++ plugins, currently reading type information

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt-creator

I am creating a simple QML/C++ Application via Qt Creator.

My project structure is like the following:

```
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── icons.cpp
    ├── icons.h
    ├── login
    │   ├── logincontroller.cpp
    │   ├── logincontroller.h
    │   └── Login.qml
    ├── main.cpp
    ├── qmlcomponents
    │   ├── enhancedpasswordtextfieldcontroller.cpp
    │   ├── enhancedpasswordtextfieldcontroller.h
    │   ├── EnhancedPasswordTextField.qml
    │   ├── EnhancedTextField.qml
    │   ├── FlatButton.qml
    │   └── RoundFlatButton.qml
    └── res
        ├── backgrounds
        │   ├── login2.png
        │   ├── login3.png
        │   └── login.png
        ├── icons
        │   ├── visibility_off.svg
        │   └── visibility.svg
        ├── qtquickcontrols2.conf
        └── resources.qrc
```

I register my `LoginController` class with the following:

```
#ifndef LOGINCONTROLLER_H
#define LOGINCONTROLLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QQmlEngine>

class LoginController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool loggingIn READ loggingIn WRITE setLoggingIn NOTIFY loggingInChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString username READ username WRITE setUsername NOTIFY usernameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString password READ password WRITE setPassword NOTIFY passwordChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString errorLabelText READ errorLabelText WRITE setErrorLabelText NOTIFY errorLabelTextChanged)

public:
    explicit LoginController(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    bool loggingIn();
    QString& username();
    QString& password();
    QString& errorLabelText();
...
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

project(tracktor VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 6.2 COMPONENTS Quick Sql REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

include_directories(
    qmlcomponents/
    login/
)

qt_add_executable(apptracktor
        main.cpp
        icons.h icons.cpp
        res/resources.qrc
)

qt_add_qml_module(apptracktor
    URI tracktor
    VERSION 1.0
    QML_FILES
        qmlcomponents/EnhancedTextField.qml
        qmlcomponents/EnhancedPasswordTextField.qml
        qmlcomponents/FlatButton.qml
        qmlcomponents/RoundFlatButton.qml

        login/Login.qml
    SOURCES
        qmlcomponents/enhancedpasswordtextfieldcontroller.h qmlcomponents/enhancedpasswordtextfieldcontroller.cpp
        login/logincontroller.cpp login/logincontroller.h
        icons.h icons.cpp
)


set_target_properties(apptracktor PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE TRUE
    WIN32_EXECUTABLE TRUE
)

target_link_libraries(apptracktor
    PRIVATE Qt6::Quick Qt6::Sql)

install(TARGETS apptracktor
    BUNDLE DESTINATION ..
    LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
```

The code compiles, and I can integrate my C++ Class with the QML file just fine. However, I get this "warning" in Qt Creator:

[image]

Everything else runs just fine. Qt also does not throw any error in the console. I was also not able to search anything on the Qt Documentation regarding this.

If I use `qmlRegisterType`, instead of specifying class in `CMakeLists.txt`, the warning does not show up. However, it seems that [this is no longer recommended in Qt 6.2 and later](https://www.qt.io/blog/qml-modules-in-qt-6.2)

It seems that it is "currently reading type information ...", as if it's trying to calculate/read something. However, it stays stuck like this. I also deleted the build directory but that did not fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

QtCreator -> Tools -> QML/JS -> RESET CODE MODEL

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

it's a bug
I'm having the same issue.
also qml components inside subdirectories shows Error M300 if you import the module, you have explicitly import the qrc path.
I deleted the build directory and resetted the code model yet it still persisted.
then I removed the imports and typed the module import again and it disappeared.